# How to use 'transloco' on `pie-chart` in Angular?

Tags: angular, charts, transloco

This is my code:

.HTML:

```
            <div fxFlex>
                <ngx-charts-pie-chart
                    [view]="view"
                    [scheme]="colorScheme"
                    [results]="single0"
                    [gradient]="gradient"
                    [legend]="showLegend"
                    [legendPosition]="legendPosition"
                    [labels]="showLabels | transloco"
                    [doughnut]="isDoughnut"
                    (select)="onSelect($event)"
                    (activate)="onActivate($event)"
                    (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)"
                    >
                </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
            </div>
```

.TS:

```
  let name = this.translocoService.translate(basket[key].name);
  console.log("the name is" , name);
```

fa.JSON:

```
{
        "فملی": "Femelli",
        "حکشتی": "Hekeshti",
        "شپنا": "Shepna",
        "ولملت": "Wlmlt",
        "ومشان": "Wmshan"
}
```

Inside the console I see `name`s like:

```
the name is فملی
the name is حکشتی
the name is شپنا
```

And the `single` JSON that will be assigned to `chart-pie` is like below:

```
single is 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "حکشتی", value: 72}
1: {name: "فملی", value: 58}
2: {name: "شپنا", value: 61}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But what I want to do is to change labels of `pie-chart` to the translated names. My chart looks like this by now that shows that the `transloco` doesn't work properly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the configuration you are passing to the chart, according to [the docs](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/v/docs-test/examples/pie-charts/pie-chart#inputs):

`labels` - `boolean` - show or hide the labels.
`labelFormatting` - `fucntion` - function that formats the label text.

Since you want to show the labels and format them you need both. set `labels` to `true` and in order to format the labels using the transloco service you need to pass the translation function to the `labelFormatting` property:

```
<ng-container *transloco="let t">
  <ngx-charts-pie-chart
    [results]="data"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [labels]="true"
    [labelFormatting]="t">
  </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
</ng-container>
```

Here is a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ngx-charts-transloco-ret3s?file=/src/app/home/home.component.html).
Another advantage of using the structural directive is that the template will render only when you have the translation values.